# Disable Zoom in FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, xaml, flowdocument

In flow documents there's this ugly zoom "feature" that you can zoom in and out. I searched and I found this to remove it:

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" FontSize="40">
        <FlowDocument>
            <!--content-->
        </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

But you can still zoom with Ctrl+MouseWheel. Is there anything I can do to disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [MinZoom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentscrollviewer.minzoom) and [MaxZoom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentscrollviewer.maxzoom) to 100:

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                            FontSize="40" MinZoom="100" MaxZoom="100">
    <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Bold>Some bold text in the paragraph.</Bold>
                Some text that is not bold.
            </Paragraph>

            <List>
                <ListItem>
                    <Paragraph>ListItem 1</Paragraph>
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem>
                    <Paragraph>ListItem 2</Paragraph>
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem>
                    <Paragraph>ListItem 3</Paragraph>
                </ListItem>
            </List>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```